# How and when to sharpen ice screws?

Tags: gear, maintenance, ice, ice-screws

Ice screws need to be sharp to be placed into the ice, and just like anything with an edge they will get dull over time.

How would **one know when to sharpen an ice screw,** and once they do need to be sharpened, what **is the correct technique** to do so?

Comment: If it can't catch on your fingernail, it isn't sharp. My experience is that sharpening anything takes hours. After you spend a few hours doing it, you being to see what works and what doesn't. People talk about guides and stuff like that, but trust me, after you have brushed a stone on a piece of metal, literally 5000 times you don't need a guide any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exist specialized tools which can assist sharpening. However those generally only work well with a specific brand/type of screw, since the angles of the screw's teeth differ.

(One example is "Lim'Ice" from Petzl, see video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzN7l4JxxpA )

Some shops also have a commercial sharpening service.
If a screw is really dull, you can improve it with a diamond file (or even a regular one) by working carefully and following the existing angles.

As to when... it depends. I sharpen my screws when they are visually damaged or when I notice that a screw takes too much effort to set and drive in. It's a trade off between the need to have sharp screws on lead and the risk that I make matters worse by botching the job.

The more you practice the better you get.

The better you are the more often it is worth it.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to tell when your screws *need* to be sharpened, because they don't cut as well and get increasingly difficult to place, but with proper maintenance your screws should *never* get to that point.

The best practice is to **sharpen your tools and gear after every climb**, even if it doesn't really need it. You don't need to go overboard, but the most serious climbers like **Will Gadd** will always go over their gear with one or two strokes of a file when putting their gear away. At the very least, gently run your file over each edge to take of any small burrs that aren't obvious from a quick visual inspection. If you wait until your tools are dull before you sharpen them, then you're going to have a difficult time getting them sharp again.

As for *how* to sharpen your screws, you can purchase specialty ice screw sharpeners, but most people just use a flat file, each screw tip gets filed from two different angles. There are plenty of [videos online demonstrating the technique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-CQbOM35oY).